# Calculating cumulative sum in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr, cumsum

How do I calculate cumulative sums in sparklyr?

dplyr:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(col = cumsum(Sepal.Length))
```

`cumsum` is not a function included in sparklyr, how can i reproduce that in sparklyr?

I think the spark SQL would be the following?:

```
SELECT
    *,
    sum(Sepal.Length) OVER (PARTITION BY Species ORDER BY index) as col
FROM
iris
```

**UPDATE:** `cumsum` is a function that can be used in sparklyr, it just needs an arrange verb to be called first (this isnt necessary in local r)

```
iris %>% 
  sdf_copy_to %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  arrange(Sepal.Length) %>%
  mutate(col = cumsum(Sepal.Length))
```

Comment: Can you use `Reduce` in `sparklyr` ? i.e `Reduce(\`+\`, iris$Sepal.Length, accumulate = TRUE)`

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Not certain how "flexible" the sql side is, but if it has window functions you could add `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` to the end after `ORDER BY index` but within the parenthesis. That would be the cumulative sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write SQL in sparklyr if you know the correct syntax, in this case the raw SQL (assuming your index is Sepal_Length) is:

```
SELECT * 
  , SUM(Sepal_Length) OVER (PARTITION BY Species ORDER BY Sepal_Length) AS CumSum
FROM iris
```

If you wanted to do it in sparklyr you would simply do:

```
iris2 <- iris %>%
          mutate(CumSum = sql("
                 SUM(Sepal_Length) OVER (PARTITION BY Species ORDER BY Sepal_Length)
                 "))
```

Answer (score 1):

The example code in the question's update is not valid syntax, and using SQL is pretty cumbersome. I believe the following would be the true sparklyr approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sparklyr) 
   
data("iris")

sc <- spark_connect()

iris %>% 
     sdf_copy_to(sc=sc, overwrite=T) %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     arrange(Sepal_Length) %>%
     mutate(col = cumsum(Sepal_Length)) %>%
     ungroup
```

Comment: this is virtually the same code. I just didnt include the very obvious `sc` object bc its obvious. If you think the `sc` should be made explicit then leave a comment or edit the question.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian, yes, it's intuitive for people familiar with R, Spark, sparklyr, and the tidyverse. You've got to remember what it was like on day two of being defeated by a new language/syntax (after slamming your head against the table for day one). You find a closed question that seems right on SO, but the code just throws an error for you. Maybe you happened to know which libraries were needed in the first place and the error is useful, maybe not. I posted this because we've all had that day, and I wanted to put a reprex out there.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be removed. Feel free to update the question but this goes against the rules of SO.